# How to prove an inequality involving factorial and power of $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to prove that $$n! \ge 2^{n-1},\qquad\text{ if}\quad n>0?$$

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I tried to prove it for n+1 but I can't

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Equality holds when $n=1$ and $2$.  Are you familiar with mathematical induction?

Comment: Yes I knew it so I prove it for n=1 then for n+1 right?

Comment: Prove it when $n=1$ and then prove it for $n+1$ assuming it's true for $n$

Comment: Yes but I need step by step how to prove it for n+1 I am new to math induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $n!\color{red}\ge2^{n-1}$ if $n>0$, because equality holds when $n=1$ or $2$.

For the induction step, we have to prove that $(n+1)!\ge 2^n$ given $n!\ge2^{n-1}$.

This follows easily from $n+1\ge2$.

Comment: But what if we include n=0?

Comment: The question specified $n>0$, but if you want to prove it for $n=0$, you could merely treat that as a separate case

Comment: But it will mean $n+1\ge1$ not 2

Comment: The question originally specified $n>0$ but has now been edited to $n\ge0$.  You are correct that my argument will not work for $n=0$; as I said, I would take $n=1$ as the base case and prove it by induction for all $n\ge1$, and I would prove the case $n=0$ separately